# Review of an UML use case diagram for an expense tracking tool

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I need to create an expense tracking tool. This tool will allow an individual user to keep a record of their expenses and also to predict financial status at a certain date.

**User Interface**

This will be built as a .NET C# windows forms desktop application. You are free to design the user interface as you wish but here are the minimal requirements.

The interface must  have at least these views:

1. A contacts view for entering and updating the details of contacts (payers
   or payees).
2. An expenses entry view for entering and updating expense details for a
   certain day.
3. A financial report view – showing all expenses for a chosen date range.
4. A view that enables the user to see their predicted financial state at a
   certain date.

For extra credit:

5. A view for entering events: appointments and tasks.
6. A weekly view displaying daily events and expenses.

It is up to you how you design your forms. We are purposely not giving you a
design example to avoid everyone having the same design. You are advised to
create mockups and storyboards and modify them iteratively as you develop your design document.
Your design decisions should be included in your report.

**Persistent storage of run time data**

The data for the expenses will be created by a view that allows the 
 specification of the expenses to be entered for a date, and this should be a programmatic dynamic interface. Once the user has finished you need to save
the expense data as an XML file and in a database of your choice. When the
application is run again (after closing) the system shall use the XML data to
populate the data on your interface. It should use the database data for the
financial report. When writing to or reading from the database the activity
should be threaded (to enable the interface to be useable while writing to an
external database)

**My UML diagram**

Can you please review the following diagram ?

[image: The Use Case Diagram]

Comment: You question as such is too broad. Please boil it down to a single specific question.

Comment: There are a couple of flaws. Wrong naming. Wrong use of `<<extend>>`. Wrong use of generalization with UCs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Are use case suitable for UI requirements ?

A [use case](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook) represents a goal that an actor wants to achieve.  It is a behavior (in general an action).  It's not how the user shall achieve the goal; not either the description of the user interface;  and even less a data model.

If you have to design a user interface (as the narrative of your exercise seems to require), you might not need UC but rather **[wireframes](https://www.experienceux.co.uk/faqs/what-is-wireframing/)** to sketch the UI.

#### What are the UC in your requirements ?

With this in mind, I would identify the following UC in your requirements:

- `Manage contact details` (#1) - I used Ma*emphasized text*nage to shorten *Enter or update* -Open question: maybe two UC after all: `Manage Payer details` + `Manage payee details`.
- `Manage  expenses for a day` (#2) - the selection of date is a detail of the UI, not a UC !
- `Report expenses` (#3) - the selection of date range is a detail of the UI, not a UC !
- `Forecast financial situation` (#4)
- `Enter (maintain?) events` (#5)
- `Report weekly situation` (#6)

#### What can be improved in your diagram ?

Now a review of your own UC diagram:

- `Select data range` could be an [include](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-include.html) for `Add transation` and `Generate reports` (caution: typo), since it is a part of the behavior and the including UC are **incomplete** without the included UC.  Note that having it as a separate UC seems to me artificially detailed and not to be recommended.
- `Select data range` should in principle not be an [extension](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-extend.html) for  `Add transation`, because an extension is **optional** and the extended UC should be complete without the extension. And here, it makes no sense to `Add a transaction` without knowing the date.
- I'd suggest to change the UC name from to an active behavior:  ***Chose/select*** data range, ***Generate/Report*** weekly view
- You currently use [generalization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case.html#generalization) in your use case.  Although it is not the most common practice, **this is perfectly legal**:  the [UC is a classifier](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case.html) and classifiers can be generalized. However, when generalization is used in an UC, it's generally with the same graphical flavour as all the other "links", separate and between only two elements, and usually not in the [shared target form](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html) ([example](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/hospital-management-use-case-diagram-example.html?context=uc-examples)).   Note that the naming of your specializations sound like nouns corresponding to data objects (e.g *Payer*) rather than behaviors (e.g. *Manage payers*).  Note also that a typo caused *Payee* to be there twice

#### *Edit: more about generalization in UC*

There is some controversy on use of inheritance in UC since its practical meaning is not as intuitive as the other kind of relations.

Inheritance could be useful when there are [several variants](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/useCaseReuse.htm) of the same UC.  It's the principle of abstraction.  But a UC should give an easy overview without loosing readers in details. So a better practice would be to keep your diagram without showing the specialisations, and have a second diagram dedicated to these details.

But personally (and looking at the comments and other answers, I'm not alone) I recommend not to use it.  It makes a simple and easy to understand diagram, in something more complex with different levels of abstraction. In this reagard, it's worth to mention [Ivar Jacobson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivar_Jacobson), the inventor of UC:

- He didn't use inheritance in his UC before they were included in UML.
- He does not either use it in his most recent work on [Use Case 2.0](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook), where he promotes the use of use-case slices to cope with variants.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I do not either recommend the use of generalisation.  Nevertheless, I think that our role here is not to decide on our own what is good or bad about the specs. In all modesty, perhaps some people out there have found a great practical use for it.  So I try to present the things as objectively as possible and I've edited to clarify.

Comment: An upvote for you, a flag for ThomasKilian remark (producing its removal it seems) ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use verb to name your UCs, *income, expense, payee, Data Range* and *Weekly View* are not UC but they correspond mainly to data.

Some UCs are missing, all what a user can ask to the system is not covered

I do not know what is the right UC for *DataRange* so difficult to check your extend / include but as Thomas Kilian I have a doubt about them

Comment: UCs are named predicate-subject(-object). Just verb is wrong. What should a UC "go" represent?

Comment: c'mon @ThomasKilian, open your mind, did you read a remark from me about what the OP can do with only "Wrong naming" ?